# How do I fix my FastCGI Pinax / Django deployment?

Tags: osx, python, macintosh, fastcgi, django

I'm running OSX Lion (posted here because this is a Unix-specific question), and am trying to deploy a Pinax project via FCGI. I have the FastCGI daemon running:

```
$ ps wwaux | grep fcgi
jonathan          522   0.0  0.2  2480420   4216   ??  S    10:54AM   0:01.14 python manage.py runfcgi method=threaded host=127.0.0.1 port=1054
jonathan         6981   0.0  0.0  2434892    536 s001  R+    2:00PM   0:00.00 grep fcgi
```

In my /etc/hosts I have:

```
FastCGIExternalServer /Users/jonathan/orthodox/orthodox.fcgi -host 127.0.0.1:1054

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin cjshayward@pobox.com
    ServerName orthodox-network.com
    ServerAlias www.orthodox-network.com orthodox.haywardfamily.org
    DocumentRoot /Users/jonathan/orthodox
    Alias /media /Users/jonathan/orthodox/media
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/(media.*)$ /$1 [QSA,L,PT]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /orthodox.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /Users/jonathan/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

On this machine I have no other VirtualHosts.

In /Users/jonathan/orthodox/orthodox.fcgi, I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os

# Add a custom Python path.
sys.path.insert(0, "/Users/jonathan")

# Switch to the directory of your project. (Optional.)
os.chdir("/Users/jonathan/orthodox")

# Set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable.
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "orthodox.settings"


from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

*And when I pull it up in a browser it hangs.*

Any advice about what I can correct to have an FCGI Django deployment?